# Why does ConcurrentQueue provide TryPeek() and TryDequeue() while Queue provides Peek() and Dequeue()?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a reason why the API was designed this way? As far as I can see, the difference between the "try" and "non-try" methods is simply getting an `InvalidOperationException` or not - which I don't see what it has to do with thread-safety. A little sidetrack here - why doesn't `Queue` and `ConcurrentQueue` implement a common interface like `IQueue`, which would provide the uniform methods, be it to use `Try...` or not?

Comment: `As far as I can see, the difference between the "try" and "non-try" methods is simply getting an InvalidOperationException or not`
did you check the source code?

Comment: Queue is there since the beginning of the .net framework while ConcurrentQueue was added later. I think the IQueue interface whould not provide much value, cause either you want a queue that is thread-safe or not. Also adding such an interface is up to the folks of the dotnet crew and changing long existing types should have a strong reason.

Comment: When using a queue concurrently then it is very common that a Dequeue may fail. It is faster to check the returned bool then to catch an exception.

Comment: @Jehof I did read both classes' source codes. Other than the way elements were retrieved, as well as the exception part, I don't particularly find a difference. For your point on having an interface probably doesn't have much value, I guess I could agree with that. However, since `ConcurrentQueue` is newer, wouldn't it be relatively easy to keep the `Dequeue()` and `Peek()` methods that are present in `Queue` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In synchronous context you can check `Count` property before dequeueing. So, if you are running code synchronously, this is enough to prevnt from exception (just like with arrays, you can get `IndexOutOfRangeexception` due to simple programming mistakes - not checking availability).

In multithreaded code, it is impossible - two thread can check, that `Count` is 1 and both can enter piece of code, where the last element is dequeued, unless you use `Semaphore` or `lock` (or other synchronization method) you are not sure whether dequeueing will be successfull or not. Thus `TryDequeue`.

Comment: Now everything seems logical now.

Answer (score -1):

`As far as I can see, the difference between the "try" and "non-try" methods is simply getting an InvalidOperationException or not - which I don't see what it has to do with thread-safety.`

Well, if you have a look at both these methods, using any decompiler (I used ilSpy), you will clearly see that there are significant differences there.

`Queue.Dequeue()` method:

```
public T Dequeue()
{
    if (_size == 0)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EmptyQueue);
    }
    T result = _array[_head];
    _array[_head] = default(T);
    _head = (_head + 1) % _array.Length;
    _size--;
    _version++;
    return result;
}
```

`ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue()` method:

```
public bool TryDequeue(out T result)
{
    while (!IsEmpty)
    {
        Segment head = m_head;
        if (head.TryRemove(out result))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    result = default(T);
    return false;
}

internal bool TryRemove(out T result)
{
    SpinWait spinWait = default(SpinWait);
    int low = Low;
    int high = High;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_low, low + 1, low) == low)
        {
            SpinWait spinWait2 = default(SpinWait);
            while (!m_state[low].m_value)
            {
                spinWait2.SpinOnce();
            }
            result = m_array[low];
            if (m_source.m_numSnapshotTakers <= 0)
            {
                m_array[low] = default(T);
            }
            if (low + 1 >= 32)
            {
                spinWait2 = default(SpinWait);
                while (m_next == null)
                {
                    spinWait2.SpinOnce();
                }
                m_source.m_head = m_next;
            }
            return true;
        }
        spinWait.SpinOnce();
        low = Low;
        high = High;
    }
    result = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't mean anything - there are implemented with different strategy (array-based vs non-blocking linkedlist), of course you would see different codes. This doesn't tell why a `TryDequeue()` is necessary, and why `Dequeue()` isn't helpful to include in the `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: So, using a different strategy ```(array-based vs non-blocking linkedlist)```, doesn't mean anything? Ok, I'll play along.